# Detect left to right swipe action on Android wear activity

Tags: android, swipe, wear-os, dismiss

This may sound familiar, I request everyone to read the issue I am facing. My requirement is straightforward. Android wear already has left-to-right swipe to dismiss the activity. However, all I want to do is detect when this action happens and then log the time in a file. My logging mechanism is ready. However, I am not sure how to get the event of right swipe on a wear activity. Please note that I still want to dismiss the activity but just keep a log of it. my activity is a simple class that extends an AppCompatActivity. I am not using any fragments. I just want to detect when that action happens and log that event and exit the app peacefully. Does GestureDetector on android help in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for a `GestureListener`, I would implement `onScroll` or `onFling` and would detect a change in the x-axis.

https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

There is also a nice video out there:

https://youtu.be/QiItWwlNwWg

Alternatively, you can also check if your `Activity` was closed by overriding either `onDestroy()` or `onPause()` in your `Activity`.

Comment: Actually, there are certain buttons in the activity that call finish() which calls onDestroy, so I cant' override these. Thanks for the video though, I will check it out!

Comment: Well, you still can use a boolean to check if a button was pressed, and do that check in `onDestroy()`.

Comment: That is what I did finally. it is a makeshift arrangement but works